# AngularJS directive runtime binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm still learning angularjs and today I wrote my second directive (hello world was the first).

I dont know whats wrong with plunkr. I couldn't able to setup AngularJS on plunkr. So sharing a image here. At least you will little idea.

**What i am doing**

I am building a contact list app, where I list users with pic, and when u click on user app shows its details, you can edit and add new user too. I'm fetching user pic from randomuser.me, for that I written a directive which is working fine. directive . Its working fine. Below is my code.

```
cbApp.directive('userPic', function() {
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     template: '<img class="circle" ng-src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/{{imageid}}.jpg">',
     scope: {
       imageid: '@'
     },
  }
});
```

**When it goes wrong**

I'm using same directive for "add contact" page. where it should show a default pic like "nouser.png", because there is no user id. Below is how I modified it.

```
    cbApp.directive('userPic', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<img class="circle" ng-src="{{imgsrc}}">',
        scope: {
          imageid: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
          scope.$watch(scope.imageid, function(value) {
              if(scope.imageid){
                scope.imgsrc = 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/'+value+'.jpg';
              }
              else
                scope.imgsrc = appConstants.default_pic;
          });
        },
        replace: true   
      };
    });
```

**Whats the actual problem**

This binds image only once, and if I click on other user it doesnt load its image. If i click user 1 then in user details page i see "user 1" pic, then if I click on "user 2" it still shows "user 1" pic.
When I try to add new user is should show "nouser.jpg" image it still shows "user 1" pic.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you have incorrect `$watch` expression. Which isn't firing your watcher function `imageid` scope variable change.

```
scope.$watch('imageid', function(value) {
     //....
});
```

Comment: If i do console.log(scope.imageid); just below the $watch, i can see values. That means i have put watch on correct variable. I dont even know is it possible and right way to do it. So asking it on stackoverflow.

Comment: One more thing, console.log(scope.imageid);  works when app loads and then when i first time click on  individual "conatct", It doesnt run after that.

Comment: Have you tried changing your watcher expression, like i suggested??

Comment: I am so sorry, i though you got me wrong. Change you suggested worked perfectly. Thank!